# Migrating Spring web application to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a web project, and I depoly it on tomcat easily. Infact I have a `WebAppInitializer` class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` (this class it's really fat), as you know every application server that supports servlet 3.0, it can easily detect it and try to boot it. Now I wonder that it could be possible to use spring boot starter and without any further configuration, I pass my `WebAppInitializer` to it and spring boot based on my `WebAppInitializer`  boots my project?

I just want to use the approach of spring-boot to deploy application on Tomcat and I don't want to use other spring-boot's facilities.

Comment: You want boot but don't want to use it then why bother...

Comment: really bad use case

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an old question. But I do not see an accepted answer and the one closest to a working one only has a link to an external resource. So here it is.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-context-initializer

> 28.4.2 Servlet Context Initialization
>
> Embedded servlet containers do not directly execute the Servlet 3.0+
>   javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer interface or Spring’s
>   org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer interface. This is
>   an intentional design decision intended to reduce the risk that third
>   party libraries designed to run inside a war may break Spring Boot
>   applications.
>
> If you need to perform servlet context initialization in a Spring Boot
>   application, you should register a bean that implements the
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer
>   interface. The single onStartup method provides access to the
>   ServletContext and, if necessary, can easily be used as an adapter to
>   an existing WebApplicationInitializer.
>
> Scanning for Servlets, Filters, and listeners
>
> When using an embedded
>   container, automatic registration of classes annotated with
>   @WebServlet, @WebFilter, and @WebListener can be enabled by using
>   @ServletComponentScan.
>
> [Tip] @ServletComponentScan has no effect in a standalone container,
>   where the container’s built-in discovery mechanisms are used instead.

I've tried it. It works

In my use case I have project containing a few dozens of webapps, designed to run on Tomcat as WAR. Lots of logics was neatly crafted into WebApplicationInitializers and it seemed there should be an easier way to reuse all this. Adding `implements ServletContextInitializer` to those initializers and exposing them as beans through `@Configuration` classes lit my webservers up with SpringBoot's embedded Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot):

> Servlet 3.0+ applications might translate pretty easily if they already use the Spring Servlet 3.0+ initializer support classes. Normally all the code from an existing WebApplicationInitializer can be moved into a SpringBootServletInitializer. If your existing application has more than one ApplicationContext (e.g. if it uses AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer) then you might be able to squash all your context sources into a single SpringApplication. The main complication you might encounter is if that doesn’t work and you need to maintain the context hierarchy. See the entry on building a hierarchy for examples. An existing parent context that contains web-specific features will usually need to be broken up so that all the ServletContextAware components are in the child context.

So yes, it's possible but you need to convert it to [`SpringBootServletInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html), which seems to be quite similar.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work. I implement a class WebAppInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {} but spring-boot doesn't call onStatup method..

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file describes precisely how to do it